# Need help using California's tax rate API in C#

Tags: c#, tax

The state of California provides this CATaxRateAPI.cs file, some of which I will post the code for at the end of this message.

Unfortunately, they do not provide any examples of how to use it that I can find, so I am struggling with how to calculate the tax rate for a particular address.

Here is my code, which is so far missing the actual submission of the request to their system because I have no idea how to do that.

```
using services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates;
       private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CARateRequest mrrequest = new CARateRequest();
            mrrequest.City = "Anaheim";
            mrrequest.State = "CA";
            mrrequest.StreetAddress = "1313 Disneyland Dr";
            mrrequest.ZipCode = 92802;

            //Obviously missing here is anything that actually sends the request to the california servers
            //var mytaxresult = GetRate(mrrequest);
            //MessageBox.Show(mytaxresult);
        }
```

I can't post the entire CATaxRateAPI.cs file because it's too long, but here is the some of file California provides. Can someone lead me in the right direction so I know how to send my request to their servers?

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates", ClrNamespace="services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates")]

namespace services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CARateRequest", Namespace="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates")]
    public partial class CARateRequest : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private string CityField;

        private System.Nullable<double> LatitudeField;

        private System.Nullable<double> LongitudeField;

        private string StateField;

        private string StreetAddressField;

        private string TokenField;

        private System.Nullable<int> ZipCodeField;

        private System.Nullable<int> ZipCodePlusFourField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string City
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CityField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CityField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<double> Latitude
        {
            get
            {
                return this.LatitudeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.LatitudeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<double> Longitude
        {
            get
            {
                return this.LongitudeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.LongitudeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return this.StateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.StateField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string StreetAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return this.StreetAddressField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.StreetAddressField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Token
        {
            get
            {
                return this.TokenField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.TokenField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<int> ZipCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ZipCodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ZipCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<int> ZipCodePlusFour
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ZipCodePlusFourField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ZipCodePlusFourField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CARateResponseCollection", Namespace="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates")]
    public partial class CARateResponseCollection : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private string AppVersionField;

        private services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponse[] CARateResponsesField;

        private string DisclaimerField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string AppVersion
        {
            get
            {
                return this.AppVersionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.AppVersionField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponse[] CARateResponses
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CARateResponsesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CARateResponsesField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Disclaimer
        {
            get
            {
                return this.DisclaimerField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.DisclaimerField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CARateResponse", Namespace="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates")]
    public partial class CARateResponse : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private int BufferSizeField;

        private services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateRequest CARateRequestField;

        private services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.Error[] ErrorsField;

        private System.DateTime ResponseDateField;

        private services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.RateInformation[] ResponsesField;

        private string TermsOfUseField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public int BufferSize
        {
            get
            {
                return this.BufferSizeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.BufferSizeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateRequest CARateRequest
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CARateRequestField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CARateRequestField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.Error[] Errors
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ErrorsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ErrorsField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.DateTime ResponseDate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ResponseDateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ResponseDateField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.RateInformation[] Responses
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ResponsesField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ResponsesField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string TermsOfUse
        {
            get
            {
                return this.TermsOfUseField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.TermsOfUseField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="Error", Namespace="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates")]
    public partial class Error : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private string CodeField;

        private string MessageField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Code
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CodeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Message
        {
            get
            {
                return this.MessageField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.MessageField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="RateInformation", Namespace="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates")]
    public partial class RateInformation : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.RateDetails DetailsField;

        private System.Nullable<double> RateField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.RateDetails Details
        {
            get
            {
                return this.DetailsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.DetailsField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<double> Rate
        {
            get
            {
                return this.RateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.RateField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="RateDetails", Namespace="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateRequest))]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponseCollection))]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponse[]))]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponse))]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.Error[]))]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.Error))]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.RateInformation[]))]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.KnownTypeAttribute(typeof(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.RateInformation))]
    public partial class RateDetails : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private string CalcMethodField;

        private object CityField;

        private string CommentsField;

        private string ConfidenceField;

        private string CountyField;

        private string JurisdictionField;

        private string TACField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string CalcMethod
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CalcMethodField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CalcMethodField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public object City
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CityField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CityField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Comments
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CommentsField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CommentsField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Confidence
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ConfidenceField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ConfidenceField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string County
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CountyField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CountyField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Jurisdiction
        {
            get
            {
                return this.JurisdictionField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.JurisdictionField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string TAC
        {
            get
            {
                return this.TACField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.TACField = value;
            }
        }
    }
}


[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates", ConfigurationName="CATaxRateAPI")]
public interface CATaxRateAPI
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/CATaxRateAPI/Hello", ReplyAction="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/CATaxRateAPI/HelloResponse")]
    string Hello(int value);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/CATaxRateAPI/Hello", ReplyAction="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/CATaxRateAPI/HelloResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> HelloAsync(int value);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/CATaxRateAPI/GetRate", ReplyAction="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/CATaxRateAPI/GetRateResponse")]
    services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponseCollection GetRate(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateRequest request);

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/CATaxRateAPI/GetRate", ReplyAction="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/CATaxRateAPI/GetRateResponse")]
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task<services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponseCollection> GetRateAsync(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateRequest request);
}

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public interface CATaxRateAPIChannel : CATaxRateAPI, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
{
}

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
public partial class CATaxRateAPIClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<CATaxRateAPI>, CATaxRateAPI
{

    public CATaxRateAPIClient()
    {
    }

    public CATaxRateAPIClient(string endpointConfigurationName) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
    {
    }

    public CATaxRateAPIClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public CATaxRateAPIClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public CATaxRateAPIClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
    {
    }

    public string Hello(int value)
    {
        return base.Channel.Hello(value);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> HelloAsync(int value)
    {
        return base.Channel.HelloAsync(value);
    }

    public services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponseCollection GetRate(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetRate(request);
    }

    public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateResponseCollection> GetRateAsync(services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates.CARateRequest request)
    {
        return base.Channel.GetRateAsync(request);
    }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[assembly: System.Runtime.Serialization.ContractNamespaceAttribute("http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates", ClrNamespace="services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates")]

namespace services.gis.boe.ca.gov.api.taxrates
{
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;


    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="CARateRequest", Namespace="http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates")]
    public partial class CARateRequest : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
    {

        private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;

        private string CityField;

        private System.Nullable<double> LatitudeField;

        private System.Nullable<double> LongitudeField;

        private string StateField;

        private string StreetAddressField;

        private string TokenField;

        private System.Nullable<int> ZipCodeField;

        private System.Nullable<int> ZipCodePlusFourField;

        public System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject ExtensionData
        {
            get
            {
                return this.extensionDataField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.extensionDataField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string City
        {
            get
            {
                return this.CityField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.CityField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<double> Latitude
        {
            get
            {
                return this.LatitudeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.LatitudeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<double> Longitude
        {
            get
            {
                return this.LongitudeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.LongitudeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string State
        {
            get
            {
                return this.StateField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.StateField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string StreetAddress
        {
            get
            {
                return this.StreetAddressField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.StreetAddressField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public string Token
        {
            get
            {
                return this.TokenField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.TokenField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<int> ZipCode
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ZipCodeField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ZipCodeField = value;
            }
        }

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
        public System.Nullable<int> ZipCodePlusFour
        {
            get
            {
                return this.ZipCodePlusFourField;
            }
            set
            {
                this.ZipCodePlusFourField = value;
            }
        }
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
```

Comment: I see that my topic was placed "on hold" based on the feedback of several users. I find stackoverflow useful for obtaining information, but I also think there is a culture of rudeness and people with superiority complexes who seem to enjoy berating people for not posting their questions in a manner they deem as suitable. Posting this let me to my answer - plain and simple. It is not "Off Topic", I just didn't understand how to send a query to the California BOE servers and the state of California provided no online documentation of their system...

Comment: My question is, as of this writing, literally the only thing that can be Googled that contains their CARateRequest object. In my opinion, it is perfectly reasonable to ask an open ended question when there is no documentation online. Granted, after some additional research, I did find that I had missed an important bit in what little documentation they did provide, but isn't that really the point of asking a question - hoping to find someone who has dealt with this before? I find this site frustrating and I fully expect to be berated for my comments because that is simply the culture here.

Comment: I rolled back your question to the version prior to the inclusion of an answer. It's inappropriate to edit the question in order to answer it, because it makes it difficult for the community to vote between alternative answers separately from the question itself. All relevant information should be included in your answer below. See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: I also disagree with the closing of this question, as it is a specific question about a specific aspect of the proper use of a published api and I have voted to reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't say what version of visual studio you have, the instructions vary slightly between them but the general idea is:

On Solution Explorer, right click References, click Add Service Reference, and add a reference to this URL:

http://services.gis.boe.ca.gov/api/taxrates/rates.svc?singlewsdl

Finish the wizard

Visual studio will create  set of client classes that you can instantiate and call methods on

Comment: This is great, thanks! I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017. I did what you said, but I'm still pretty unclear how I'm supposed to get the information. I'll poke around for a bit, but if you have any additional help to offer, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: For example, CARateRequest is a class, and I can set properties to set the address. There is only one "method" associated with that class that I can see - something called "RaisePropertyChanged(string) and I don't really understand what that would do. I can't really see any obvious way to submit this to them once I've set the properties and I seem to have the same problem when I look at other client classes - I don't really understand how to get it submitted to them.

Comment: Never mind. I got it finally. Thanks again.

Comment: I didn't have vs, was posting from a phone, but typically adding a service reference gives you a Client that has the action methods on it, like `var rc = new RateClient();` that you call like `rc.GetTaxRateForZipCode(12345);` etc. Most of the classes you see are probably data-holding request and response classes

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is looking for the specific answer on the CA Tax rate API, Here is my revised code above that works now. I used the advice from Caius Jard's answer to add the service reference and then used this code:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // Use the 'client' variable to call operations on the service.
        CARateRequest mrrequest = new CARateRequest();
        mrrequest.City = "Anaheim";
        mrrequest.State = "CA";
        mrrequest.StreetAddress = "1313 Disneyland Dr";
        mrrequest.ZipCode = 92802;
        CATaxRateAPIClient client = new CATaxRateAPIClient();
        var myrate = client.GetRate(mrrequest);
        MessageBox.Show(myrate.CARateResponses[0].Responses[0].Rate.ToString()); 
        // Close the client.
        client.Close();
    }
```